# Display the custom list templates available within a site collection in SharePoint 2010

Tags: list-template

How to display the custom list templates available within a site collection in SharePoint 2010 using Powershell script?

> I tried to use the below code:

```
$site = Get-SPSite "https://..."
$web = $site.RootWeb
$template = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
```

But it is not returning anything.But there are custom list templates within the list template gallery.

Thanks so much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's something related to your secure site "https". On my end it is working

```
  $site= Get-SPSite "http://webapp/sites/site1"
  $SPWeb = $site.RootWeb
  $site.GetCustomListTemplates($SPWeb)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of the permissions of the account under which you are running the script.
You should at least have designer permissions. Give it a try.